# How to match RFC3339 timestamp using Regex?

Tags: regex, erlang

I want i check the format of timestamp which is described in [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

Here is the examples:

```
"1996-12-19T16%3A39%3A57-08%3A00"

"1996-12-19T15%3A39%3A27%2E20-08%3A00"

"2013-07-08T18%3A07%3A13Z"

"2013-07-08T18%3A07%3A13.49Z“
```

I have run one re pattern, but it only works for the first and second examples.

```
"\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}%3A\\d{2}%3A\\d{2}(%2E\\d+)?[+-]\\d{2}%3A\\d{2}"
```

Comment: What about percent-decoding it first?

Comment: What tool/language are you using this regex in?

Comment: I am using Erlang.But i think the language is not important.

Comment: It is, both for the formatting of the regex, and the availability of certain regex features (that differ from flavour to flavour).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below regex would match all the above four examples,

```
"^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}%3A\\d{2}%3A\\d{2}(?:%2E\\d+)?[A-Z]?(?:[+.-](?:08%3A\\d{2}|\\d{2}[A-Z]))?$"
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/yK8xI1/9)

You forget to mark `[+-]\\d{2}%3A\\d{2}` as optional and also forget to add regex to match `Z` and `.49Z` in third and fourth line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cann't understand it, what it the meaning of `?:`? I think your regex can match more than the four examples?

Comment: `(?:...)` is called a non-capturing group anything inside this group won't be captured. And the `?` after the non-capturing group makes the non-capturing group as an optional one. IT may or maynot present on the string. If you don't want to match the lines which exceeds more than this characters then add a `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Comment: This matches invalid dates like `2000-99-99` and invalid times like `99:99:99`. You could fix that by using something like `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` (example for months). But it gets quite complicated if you want to support the correct day count per months. Also there are leap years and seconds to make it even worse.